# Python: Convert non-specifically formatted string into dictionary?

Tags: python, dictionary

I'm scraping my router's connected devices page to get a list of who's home. If I set a short DHCP release, I can do this pretty easily through a different method. However, I'd like to instead be able to turn the following string into a dictionary to complete this a more optimal way:

```
wldev = [['eth1','8C:3A:E3:95:77:21',-85,54000,1000,31365,0],
['eth1','A4:77:33:0C:E0:BE',-41,72223,72223,42239,0],
['eth2','58:B0:35:7A:20:C1',-34,104000,130000,21017,1],
['eth2','A4:77:33:66:BC:F6',-48,39000,58500,43956,1]]
```

This actually comes out all on one line. The closest I can get is making it a tuple using:

```
wldev = wldev.replace(']','}')
wldev = wldev.replace('eth0\''',', 'eth0\': {').replace('eth1\''',', 'eth1\': {').replace('eth2\''',', 'eth2\': {').replace('br0\''',', 'br0\': {').replace('br1\''',', 'br\': {')
wldev = wldev.replace('0}', '0\'}}').replace('1}', '1\'}}').replace(',','\',\'').replace('\'\'','\'').replace('\',\'{',',{')
```

But this is ugly. I'm new to Python and don't know much about RegEx, but surely there must be an easier way. Probably something simple. Any ideas?

Comment: How did you end up with that format?

Comment: It looks like a valid json string, so you could use ast.literal as suggest or json.loads() either way you end up with a list, which you can quickly turn into a dict.

Comment: The original `wldev=' ? Using requests on the devices-list page. And then .find() to pull out just the wldev section.

Comment: Given the input data shown, what do you want the dictionary to contain? Dictionaries have unique keys, often strings, that map to values which can be anything.

Comment: In the example above, I'd like to be able to call the `72223` fron `eth1` using something like `wldev[1][4]`

Answer (score 3):

Use [`ast.literal_eval()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

> *Safely* evaluate an expression node or a Unicode or Latin-1 encoded string containing a Python literal or container display. The string or node provided may only consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, booleans, and None.

```
from ast import literal_eval

print(literal_eval(wldev))
```

Demo:

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> 
>>> wldev = """[['eth1','8C:3A:E3:95:77:21',-85,54000,1000,31365,0],
... ['eth1','A4:77:33:0C:E0:BE',-41,72223,72223,42239,0],
... ['eth2','58:B0:35:7A:20:C1',-34,104000,130000,21017,1],
... ['eth2','A4:77:33:66:BC:F6',-48,39000,58500,43956,1]]"""
>>> 
>>> literal_eval(wldev)
[['eth1', '8C:3A:E3:95:77:21', -85, 54000, 1000, 31365, 0], ['eth1', 'A4:77:33:0C:E0:BE', -41, 72223, 72223, 42239, 0], ['eth2', '58:B0:35:7A:20:C1', -34, 104000, 130000, 21017, 1], ['eth2', 'A4:77:33:66:BC:F6', -48, 39000, 58500, 43956, 1]]
```

As a result you get a Python list of lists printed. To make a dictionary out of it and since there are non-unique first items in the sublists, I would use a [`collections.defaultdict()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

```
from collections import defaultdict

l = literal_eval(wldev)

d = defaultdict(list)
for item in l:
    d[item[0]].append(item[1:])
```

Comment: @PadraicCunningham got your "dictionary making" part into the answer and had to go further with it, since the first items in sublists are non-unique..grouped them with defaultdict.

Comment: Hmmm...if I do that and then print d, I get defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {'4': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ',': ['', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', ''], ']': ['', '', '', '', '']....and it basically repeats like that for ~400 characters. 

Part of the problem might be that `wldev` is actually printed on one line. Using `literal_eval`, I don't get any spaces after commas as yours shows.

Comment: @syndac well, then `wldev` is not something you've presented. Please post what the real value is.

Comment: @alecxe ['eth1','8C:3A:E3:95:77:21',-85,54000,1000,32920,0],['eth1','A4:77:33:0C:E0:BE',-41,72223,72223,43794,0],['eth2','58:B0:35:7A:20:C1',-34,104000,130000,22571,1],['eth2','A4:77:33:66:BC:F6',-49,39000,58500,45510,1]]
[['eth1','8C:3A:E3:95:77:21',-85,54000,1000,32920,0],['eth1','A4:77:33:0C:E0:BE',-41,72223,72223,43794,0],['eth2','58:B0:35:7A:20:C1',-34,104000,130000,22571,1],['eth2','A4:77:33:66:BC:F6',-49,39000,58500,45510,1]]

Some values might change a little each time I `requests`, but otherwise, that's a copy/paste from the console. All on a single line

Comment: @alecxe Well I feel dumb. I added the triple quotes to my wldev to make it look like yours, thinking it would put us on the same page. Obviously, it did not and that's what caused the error.

Comment: Now, if I print d, I get:

`defaultdict(<class 'list'>`....followed by basically the same as wldev. Should it have that part in the beginning?

Comment: @syndac this is the defaultdict's string representation. What is important is that `d` is a Python data structure, containing first sublist items as keys and the rest as values. Do `pprint(dict(d))` to have it presented in a readable format, where `from pprint import pprint`..

Comment: @alecxe Gotcha. Thanks. This is close to what I'm looking for. I probably should have said this initially, but in the example above, I'd like to be able to call the `72223` fron `eth1` using something like `wldev[1][4]`

I get `IndexError: list index out of range` if I try that now. Haven't had time to really think through it yet, but if you have ideas, I'm very open to it.

Comment: @syndac you can just leave it as list of lists: `l[1][4]` from my example above.